# My function is asynchronous, why do I get a NetworkOnMainThread Exception?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, exception, networking

This is the object where all my API calls are made. Sometimes when I make a call to this function, I receive a NetworkOnMainThread exception. It doesn't happen every time. I'm confused because I've made this function asynchronous... why am I still getting this exception?

```
object APICaller{

    private const val apiKey = "API_KEY_HERE"

    //Live Data Objects
    var errorCode = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    var fetchedResponse = MutableLiveData<Response>()


    //Asynchronous network call
    suspend fun networkCall(query: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default){

        val apiURL = "API_URL_HERE"

        try{
            //Get response
            val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(Request.Builder().url(apiURL).build()).execute()

            if(response.isSuccessful){
                //UI changes (including changes to LiveData values) must be performed on main thread.
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
                    fetchedResponse.value = response
                }.also{
                    Log.i("Response Succ", response.toString())
                }
            } else {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
                    errorCode.value =
                        ToastGenerator.REQUEST_ERROR
                }.also{
                    Log.i("Response Fail", response.toString())
                }
            }
            //Catch any thrown network exceptions whilst attempting to contact API
        } catch(e: Exception){
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
                errorCode.value =
                    ToastGenerator.NETWORK_ERROR
            }.also{
                Log.i("Network Fail", e.message.toString())
            }
        }

    }

}
```

There are three other classes that make utilise return value from the APICaller networkCall() function. The first is a ViewModel that references it directly.

```
class BrowseViewModel: ViewModel() {

    //LiveData Objects
    //Transformations listen to LiveData in APICaller and map it to LiveData in this ViewModel
    var errorCode: LiveData<Int>? = Transformations.map(APICaller.errorCode){ code ->
        return@map code
    }
    var obtainedResponse: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(APICaller.fetchedResponse){ response ->
        return@map response.body()?.string()
    }

    //Upon a search request, make a network call
    fun request(query: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch{
            APICaller.networkCall(query)
        }
    }

    //Convert API response to GameData object
    fun handleJSONString(jsonString: String, file: String) : List<GameData>{
        return DataTransformer.JSONToGameData(JSONObject(jsonString), JSONObject(file))
    }
}
```

The second is an fragment that calls the ViewModel's function.

```
fun request(query: String){
     browseViewModel.request(query)
     progressSpinner?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

The third is an Activity that calls upon the Fragment's function.

```
private fun makeRequest(query: String){
    browseFragment.let{
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, it).commit()
        it.request(query)
    }
}
```

Could it be related to these other functions?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why did you include `withContext()`. You can change it with a suspend function without `withContext` and start a new Coroutine when calling your function. This might be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly what could go wrong in your code, but it could definitely be much cleaner, which possibly would resolve your issue, or at least make it easier to find the error.

A good strategy with `suspend` functions is to design them to always be called from a Main dispatcher. Then you can freely make UI calls in them and wrap only the background parts with `withContext`. So your above function could move the `withContext()` down to only wrap the `execute()` call, and all your Handler usage could be removed. (Incidentally, those would have been cleaner using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`.)

However, Retrofit already provides a suspend function version of making a call, so you don't even need the `withContext` wrapper. Just use `await()` instead of `execute()` and your suspend function would collapse down to:

```
suspend fun networkCall(query: String) {

    val apiURL = "API_URL_HERE"

    try{
        val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(Request.Builder().url(apiURL).build()).await()
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            Log.i("Response Succ", response.toString())
            fetchedResponse.value = response
        } else {
            Log.i("Response Fail", response.toString())
            errorCode.value = ToastGenerator.REQUEST_ERROR
        }
    } catch(e: Exception){
        Log.i("Network Fail", e.message.toString())
        errorCode.value = ToastGenerator.NETWORK_ERROR
    }

}
```

And then instead of using GlobalScope, you should use a `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope` so your coroutines don't leak UI components. And the `await()` suspending function above supports cancellation, so if for instance your ViewModel is destroyed due to the associated Fragment or Activity going out of scope, your network call will be cancelled automatically for you.

```
fun request(query: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        APICaller.networkCall(query)
    }
}
```

If the problem persists, study your stack trace closely to see where you might be making the error.